# Как применить стиль textDecoration = "underLine" для известного тега в функции через JS

Tags: javascript, css

Задача - создать функцию, которая принимает тег, ищет все теги по странице и подчеркивает их. Т.Е. если отправить туда `p` то все теги **`p`** на странице подчеркиваются.

Я знаю как можно найти все теги на странице -

```
document.querySelectorAll(`document.${tag}`);
```

где `tag` это название тега. так же понимаю как можно подчеркнуть -

```
tag.style.textDecoration = "UnderLine";
```

однако совершенно не понимаю как
это соединить, что бы работало нормально, вот моя попытка

```js
'use strict'

function tagCheck(tag) {
  let tags = document.querySelectorAll(`document.${tag.value}`);
  for (let elem of tags) {
    tags.style.textDecoration = "UnderLine";
  }
  return (0);
}

butId.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let nothing = tagCheck(tag.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="tag">
<button id="butId">Кнопка</button>
<p>Хехв</p>
```

`button, input text и p` для проверки.

Как и было очевидно, оно не сработало

p.s. я в JS 2 недели не пишите сложно не бейте больно

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если правильно понял задачу, вот такой вариант

```js
let button = document.getElementById('butId');

function tagCheck(tag){
  let tags = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);   
  for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    tags[i].style.textDecoration = "UnderLine";
  }
}
button.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  let input = document.getElementById('inp');
  tagCheck(input.value);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">            
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <input type="text" id="inp">
   <button id="butId">Кнопка</button>
   <p>Хехв</p>
</body>
```